# Docker running on Centos7 with a Windows 7 container

Tags: docker, centos, containers

Is it possible as the title states to run a Docker container with the HOST being Centos7 and the CONTAINER being Windows 7?  I have not had any luck with Google pulling down meaningful results, nor is there a solution on SO.

Update, the link to use "boot2docker" offers no real context or any value to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That would not be possible.

The containers all share the hosts kernel, so they cannot be different types of operating system.